# Pass PHP session variable into HTML form

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

I have session variables that are posted from a form on another php page, and I can echo them by using:

```
<?php $_SESSION['newsletterSignup'] = $_POST['newsletterSignup'];
echo "Email = ". $_SESSION['newsletterSignup'];
?>
```

But I can't seem to insert these into a HTML form field:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="36" "value="<?php echo $_SESSION['newsletterSignup'];?>" class="text-input" onBlur="emailval()" />
```

Comment: did you `session_start()` ?

Comment: Elaborating Shivan's question: You need `session_start()` at the beginning of every page.

Comment: Yes I have <?php session_start(); ?> at the top

Comment: As I said, I have no issues with echo'ing the variable on the same page as the form, I just can't get it to echo in the form field

Comment: @DLO do you have `session_start()` at the top of **every page** using `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work...the quote before value was probably screwing it up

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="36" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['newsletterSignup'];?>" class="text-input" onBlur="emailval()" />
```

Comment: @DLO - Do you use an editor or IDE with syntax highlighting? It makes those things very easy to spot.

Comment: Using Dreamweaver atm, but do have eclipse

Answer (score 2):

you use

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="36" "value="<?php echo $_SESSION['newsletterSignup'];?>" class="text-input" onBlur="emailval()" />
```

A `"` to many. Here is the fix

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="36" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['newsletterSignup'];?>" class="text-input" onBlur="emailval()" />
```

Also, did you use session_start(); ?